# Use default value of Subclass method in an array of Base class

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, subclass, default-value

Is there any way that `cout << a[0]->function();` can give a 5 instead?

At the moment, it takes the default value of the base class and runs the method of the subclass.

But I want it to run the method of the subclass and take the default value of the subclass.

```cpp
class Basis
{
public:
    virtual int function(int i = 1) { return 2; }
};

class Sub : public Basis
{
public:
    int function(int i = 5) override { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    Basis* a[2];
    a[0] = new Sub();
    cout << a[0]->function(); //gives 1
}
```

Comment: That's neat. The default values are set by the definition, not the implementation and it's the implementation that winds up known at runtime. Since the definition for `a[0]->function()` is going to be for the base class, I've never given it any thought before, but I can see how this is unexpected. Bet's there's a really nifty paragraph or two in the Standard covering this behaviour.

Comment: And here it is: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is calling `function()` via a `Basis*` pointer, so it is going to use the default value defined by `Basis`, there is no way for `Sub` to override that.  Calling `function()` via a `Sub*` pointer would use the default value defined by `Sub` instead.

So, given the code you have shown, the easiest way I can think of doing what you are asking for is to use function overloads, eg:

```
class Basis
{
public:
    virtual int function() { return function(1); }
    virtual int function(int i) { return 2; }
};

class Sub : public Basis
{
public:
    int function() override { return function(5); }
    int function(int i) override { return i; }
};

int main()
{
    Basis* a[2];
    a[0] = new Basis();
    a[1] = new Sub();
    cout << a[0]->function(); //gives 2
    cout << a[1]->function(); //gives 5
}
```